# Rigify IK problem in Blender 2.8

Tags: rigging, rigify

So I was testing rigify in 2.8 and I was not able to make the IK working. I just add metarig, Generate the rig right away and IK is not working - hands and knees are not bending as expected. All the sliders were correct. And what I did to make it work is to teak the Rest Length on the selected MCH bones, as shown in the attached grab. 
Is this a correct behaviour? Did I solve the problem correct way or it will give me problems down the road?
Thanks in advance.

[image: SCREENGRAB]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about issues with unfinished experimental development versions of Blender

Comment: yes thanks for standing in the way of ppl helping each other out on a beta version. so whats your point exactly? that it's a beta? well guess people will still need help or clarification... seriously, there are already a ton of topics here about blender 2.8 -.- this StackExchange can be so counterproductive and shooting itself in the butt, it's unbelievable. Btw: I profited probably the same amount from by wanna-be-wise-guys closed topics as from open ones and never came across bad answers or a bad thread development in any way.

Comment: "you can only edit comments within 5 minutes". well here's another stupid stack exchange limitation right there, but let me just create another comment, makes more sense haha :D btw2: it's not experimental!! ;)